# Storing the same Strings on firebase like string1, string2, string3

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I store equal strings os firebase ?

I have a class on firebase that allows me to add students but I don't know how do I create student1, student2, student3.

This is the code:

```
 bSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!validateForm()) {
                return;
            }
            if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                final DatabaseReference add_student_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user_id).child("Alunos");
                final String anome = aNome.getText().toString();
                Map newPost = new HashMap();
                newPost.put("Aluno", anome);
                add_student_db.setValue(newPost);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(AddStudent.this, "Erro ao Adicionar o Nome",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

"Aluno" is student in portuguese.

My child stops at "Alunos" and I want it to create inside of "Alunos", "Aluno1", "Aluno2"...

Thanks.

**Update:**

I solved my problem by doing this:

```
 if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                final String anome = aNome.getText().toString();
                if (filePath != null){
                    final StorageReference add_student_sr = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user_id).child("Alunos").child(anome);
                    StorageReference riversRef = add_student_sr.child(anome+"_profilePic.jpg");
                    riversRef.putFile(filePath)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Uploaded ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    String downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                                    String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                    final DatabaseReference add_student_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user_id).child("Alunos").child(anome);
                                    Map newPost = new HashMap();
                                    newPost.put("profilePic", downloadUrl);
                                    add_student_db.setValue(newPost);
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                    double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();

                                }
                            });
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to handle this is to call `push()`.

When you call `push()` Firebase creates a new unique location under the location. You can then call `setValue` on that new location

```
final DatabaseReference add_student_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user_id).child("Alunos");
final String anome = aNome.getText().toString();
add_student_db.push().setValue(anome);
```

Every time you run this code a new child node will be created under `/Users/$user_id/Alunos` with `"Aluno": "Name from aNome"`.

Comment: Ohhh, I didn't explained it very well. I want to create aluno1, aluno2... Not aluno1= aNome. So, inside aluno1, aluno2... I can create nome = anome.

Comment: I still don't understand what that means. Can you edit your question to include the JSON (as text, no screenshot) that you want to create from your Android app?

Comment: Updated! I'm sorry for my bad explanation. I don't speak english very well.

Comment: I updated my answer to match your JSON. The only difference will be in the name of the keys. My snippet uses `push()` since (for reasons explained [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) and [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html)) Firebase doesn't have a sequential unique ID operation.